# How do i add locale.json files in seperate folder in i18next?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization, translation

This is my fiddle link :https://jsfiddle.net/La1c1p7f/1/

Instead of giving variable name `"resStore": resources` , I want to give json files like en.json, ch.json in a seperate folder . In angularjs we can give folder path like this

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/ccs/nls/lang_',
    suffix: '.json'
})
```

How can i give in i18n? Please help me in doing.Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you know about angular then you know about ajax and what it can do

Comment: @madalinivascu Im not an expert in angular. I saw that in angular we can do like this. If you know please help. Thanks

Comment: that means you don't know javascript well enough, familiarize yourself with ajax and if you encounter other problems don't hesitate to add a question here

Answer (score 0):

if related to loading json with i18next you should have a look into the xhr backend https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend